# Value not updated after posted data

Tags: php, session

I got a session which contains products. New products are added to the session (which is an array) as a post through an a href like so:

```
<a class="offertelink" href="offerte.php?product='.$productcr[0]['id'].'">Request a quote</a>
```

At the top of my page I got a basket which counts the array and displays how much products are in the session. But when I add a product, the basket at the top shows my empty message 'You have no added products', only after refreshing there is 1 product. Why is that?

My code:
(the link i posted above is on the productlisting)
The entire page is inbetween an `ob_start();` and `ob_flush();` so I can use a header location redirect after the headers have been sent (maybe that has something to do with it?).

quote.php:

```
ob_start();
include 'includes/header.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['product'])){
    $_SESSION['product'] = array();
}

// Check if $_GET['product'] is is set
if(isset($_GET['product']) && !in_array($_GET['product'], $_SESSION['product'])){
    $_SESSION['product'][] = $_GET['product'];
}
```

Included on this page is the header (included on every page), which has the following code for the basket:

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="offerte.php"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Quote</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <div class="offertemand">
            <?
            if(count($_SESSION['product']) == 0){
                echo '<span style="padding:8px;">No products added</span>';
            }else{
                $aantal = count($_SESSION['product']);
                echo '<a class="offerteitem" href="offerte.php"><span class="aantal">'.$aantal.'</span></a>';
                echo '<a style="font-size:13px;" href="offerte.php">Go to quote page</a>';
            }
            ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

So when the product is added to the session and the user is redirected to the quote page I have to refresh the page for any products to be seen inside the basket. While the product I added is visible in the productlist on my quote page.

Comment: did u start session?

Comment: @user1844933 Yeah, `session_start()` is at the top of my connection file, which is at the top of my header.php

Comment: maybe you're generating the basket html content after u're adding the product to the session ?

Answer (score 0):

is the 3rd code (basket) included in `header.php`?

if so, you must add `product` to `$_SESSION` before including `header.php`(or any other codes that requires `$_SESSION['product']`).

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['product'])){
    $_SESSION['product'] = array();
}

// Check if $_GET['product'] is is set
if(isset($_GET['product']) && !in_array($_GET['product'], $_SESSION['product'])){
    $_SESSION['product'][] = $_GET['product'];
}
include 'includes/header.php';
```